# AT command - 3G connection to another cell (second version)

Tags: cell, at-command, modem, rssi

I know there is already the same question, but because I cannot comment it (I don't have enough votes), I have to open a new question. So I want to know if it's possible to connect to another cell. But rather connect to another, is that possible to avoid to connect to the first one. What I mean is, with the AT+CREG command it is possible to have the cell ID of the base station, it that possible to prohibite the modem to connect to this one?

My main purpose is to receive th RSSI of all the cell around me, and not only the one I am connected to. Until now I was using AT^HSCQ but this just give you the RSSI, RSCP and EC/IO of the cell I am connected with.

So what I wanted to do is to list all the cell around me with AT+COPS, and then step by step, prohibite each cell to have at the end the rssi of every cell.

Maybe there is a command that can already give the RSSI of all the networks around me? I looked in the the AT command interface book from Huawei, I did not find it.

edit 21/04/2015:

I found some commands who can help me such as AT^MONI, AT^SMONC or AT^SMOND. Unfortunately, i think that my Huawei E3531 does not support those commands. Any body knows? Anybody already tried those commands with an other modem/cell phone?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried `+CLAC` to list available commands?

Comment: thank you, but I don't have any answer when I try this command

Comment: You are doing `AT+CLAC` right?

Comment: http://www.ctiforum.com/standard/standard/etsi/0707.pdf

Comment: Yes, I did AT+CLAC. And I tried with my script and also with minicom in the terminal. With my script (using pyserial) it sends me back none, and with Minicom it sends me nothing.
Ok, I am going to read and try what I find in your PDF. Do you think that it is possible that my Huawei E3531 can be incompatible with some commands?

Comment: In fact I was already using something similar:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vuHH8OW_uK0J:download-c.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter%3FdownloadId%3D14386+&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=at#93

Comment: I am going to try with a roaming SIM card, what do you think about that? Because it seems that my modem does not support those commands.